# insert images into a tabular environment

Tags: tables, graphics

I have 8 images, in which i want two images across, by 4 images down. I am trying to do this with the following code:

```
\begin{figure}[htb]
\centering
  \begin{tabular}{@{}cccc@{}}
    \includegraphics[scale=0.4]{../random_forest/TP-Pred/program/error1.jpg} 
    \includegraphics[scale=0.4]{../random_forest/AFP-AFP-like/program/error1.jpg}
    \includegraphics[scale=0.4]{../random_forest/TP-Pred/program/error1.jpg} 
    \includegraphics[scale=0.4]{../random_forest/AFP-AFP-like/program/error1.jpg}  
    \multicolumn{4}{c}{\includegraphics[width=.23\textwidth]{example-image-a}}
  \end{tabular}
  \caption{A plot of the random forest error split culmulatively over the 4 sets of features}
\end{figure}
```

however all 4 images appear on the same horizontal line. How do I get them to appear like:

```
image 1      image 2
image 3      image 4
image 5      image 6
image 7      image 8
```

thanks in advance.

Comment: use \\ within a `tabular` to start a new line :)

Comment: also you have a 4 column tabular but have put all the images in the same cell you need `&` between the cells.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I gather the eight jpegs are all the same size, right? In that case, there's no need to embed them in a `tabular` environment. You could do the following instead:

```
\begin{figure}[htb]
    \includegraphics[width=0.45\textwidth]{../random_forest/TP-Pred/image1.jpg}%
    \hspace*{\fill}% induce some horizontal separation between images 1 and 2
    \includegraphics[width=0.45\textwidth]{../random_forest/TP-Pred/image2.jpg}

    \includegraphics[width=0.45\textwidth]{../random_forest/TP-Pred/image3.jpg}%
    \hspace*{\fill}% induce some horizontal separation between images 3 and 4
    \includegraphics[width=0.45\textwidth]{../random_forest/TP-Pred/image4.jpg}

    \includegraphics[width=0.45\textwidth]{../random_forest/TP-Pred/image5.jpg}%
    \hspace*{\fill}% induce some horizontal separation between images 5 and 6
    \includegraphics[width=0.45\textwidth]{../random_forest/TP-Pred/image6.jpg}

    \includegraphics[width=0.45\textwidth]{../random_forest/TP-Pred/image7.jpg}%
    \hspace*{\fill}% induce some horizontal separation between images 7 and 8
    \includegraphics[width=0.45\textwidth]{../random_forest/TP-Pred/image8.jpg}

  \caption{A plot of the random forest error split culmulatively over the 4 sets of features}
\end{figure}
```

Observe that a blank line will automatically force the following images to show up on a new "line". If you want more than the minimum amount of vertical separation, you could insert directives such as `\smallskip`, `\medskip`, or `\bigskip` (while still leaving a blank line to force a line break).

---

*Addendum*: If you really want/need to embed the images in a tabular structure, I would recommend you use the `tabular*` environment and set its width to `\textwidth` to assign as much width as possible to the images. The somewhat odd looking construct `@{\extracolsep{\fill}}` spreads the two columns maximally apart.

```
\begin{figure}[htb]
\begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{@{} c @{\extracolsep{\fill}} c @{}}
    \includegraphics[width=0.45\textwidth]{../random_forest/TP-Pred/image1.jpg}&
    \includegraphics[width=0.45\textwidth]{../random_forest/TP-Pred/image2.jpg}\\
    \includegraphics[width=0.45\textwidth]{../random_forest/TP-Pred/image3.jpg}&
    \includegraphics[width=0.45\textwidth]{../random_forest/TP-Pred/image4.jpg}\\
    \includegraphics[width=0.45\textwidth]{../random_forest/TP-Pred/image5.jpg}&
    \includegraphics[width=0.45\textwidth]{../random_forest/TP-Pred/image6.jpg}\\
    \includegraphics[width=0.45\textwidth]{../random_forest/TP-Pred/image7.jpg}&
    \includegraphics[width=0.45\textwidth]{../random_forest/TP-Pred/image8.jpg}\\
\end{tabular*}
\caption{A plot of the random forest error split culmulatively over the 4 sets of features}
\end{figure}
```